# How do I return a hash with relational data using parse.com?

Tags: parse-platform

I have a Post class and I want to get the products associated to it. I'd like to write a single query that fetches all of the posts with the products associated to them. Below is a rough idea of what I'd like the hash to looks like.

**Schema:**
Post - objectId, title
PostItem - post(pointer), product(pointer)
Product - objectId, title, price

**Output I want**
    {'results':
      [{'objectId':'blah', 'title':'The Post',
        'products':
          [{'objectId':'14',
            'title':'First product',
            'price':'20'
          },
          {'objectId':'26',
            'title':'Second product',
            'price':'55'
          }]
        },
        {'objectId':'blah2', 'title':'Second post',
          [{'objectId':'38',
            'title':'Some product',
            'price':'54'
          },
          {'objectId':'26',
            'title':'Another Product',
            'price':'88'
          }]
        }]
      }

Is this possible to do in one query? How would I do this using curl and parse.com?

Comment: Did you give the "include" parameter in Parse Query a try? It's documented at https://parse.com/docs

Comment: I've been trying that, but it seems include only works if you have a pointer column on the class your querying.  I'm querying Post and trying to get the products for it, but Post doesn't have any pointers. The pointers actually live in PostItem, which is treated as an association table.

Comment: I believe I need to drop the PostItem table and add a array of pointers column to the post table.  Still trying to figure it out now.

Answer (score 0):

If this is a many-to-many relationship, use a Parse relationship.

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to use the `include` key option alongside pointers. Since it's been nearly a year since you posted, I assume you figured it out, but lurkers can read more about this (in Javascript) [here](https://www.parse.com/docs/js_guide#queries-relational).